# Maximum tag length and tag for exponential time algorithms

Tags: feature-request, tags

I wanted to tag a question with `exponential-time-algorithms` and I got the error-message:

```
Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
* 'exponential-time-algorithms' exceeds maximum tag length of 24
```

So, I used the far less elegant tag `exponential-algorithms`.

Is there a way around the restriction of maximum tag length 24?
Do you have a better suggestion for the tag `exponential-algorithms`? I can think of `exact-algorithms`, but I don't like it too much because, by definition, an algorithm gives you a(n exact) solution to your problem (in the view that approximation algorithms solve a more relaxed version of the problem).

Comment: I think "exact-algorithms" would be ok, too; it seems to be the standard term used in the field even though it makes little sense.

Comment: I flagged this post for moderator attention to ask moderators to merge and synonymize [exponential-algorithms] → [exp-time-algorithms].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that the 24-character restriction cannot be lifted, how about [exp-time-algorithms]?  But I am not completely sure if <del>we really need</del> it is really useful to have a tag for exponential-time algorithms.

Answer (score 3):

How about `exp-time` ? this could be coupled with [algorithms], or could be coupled with cc.complexity-theory for discussions about EXP

Comment: I think I like that. I'll wait a bit before changing my tag in case some other suggestion gets a lot more votes.

Comment: "exp-time" sounds a bit too much like a complexity class to me...

Comment: @Jukka: Good point. So, maybe exp-time-algorithms is better after all.

Comment: You could use [exponential-time] if the only concern is a possible confusion with the complexity class EXPTIME.  However, imagine that someone wants to highlight questions about exponential-time algorithms by setting “Interesting Tags.”  The catch is that it is not possible to set a combination of tags as “interesting.”  Honestly speaking, though, I cannot imagine that anyone is interested in exponential-time algorithms without being interested in algorithms in general, hence my question about the usefulness of the tag.